# Is there an object wrapper for primitive values that allows mutating them from a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, primitive-types

Consider:

```
boolean somethingHappened = false;
Runnable doHappen = () -> { somethingHappened = true; }
```

You cannot do that, because `somethingHappened` is not final. The rationale is that generally, you should not need to change captured variables from the lambda scope. But for example when using `Stream.forEach` this is not necessary an unusual need.

I could write a wrapper of course:

```
class Wrap<T> 
{
    public T value;
}
```

And then I would access `somethingHappened.value` and change that.

I was just wondering if a wrapper of this kind already exists in the standard Java library. I only know of `Optional` which is immutable. I could abuse an array `final boolean[] mutableBool = { false }` but that is horrible.

Comment: Yeah, that what my question says I consider a little horrible. But if I don't get an answer, I'll probably do that. Also btw you can just write `boolean[] x = { false };`, new is implied here.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read it properly.

Comment: I'm not sure they are the correct way to go about this, but the classes in the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Java library. But Apache Commons Lang has [Mutable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/Mutable.html) for this. It offers subclasses for each of the primitive wrappers, but each of them is mutable (like MutableInt, MutableBoolean etc)

You can consider if using it would be feasible for you.

---

**UPDATE**

AtomicBoolean is another option. It allows you to share it between threads and update the boolean value it holds.

---

My $0.02 - Whenever I have to update a variable from a lambda, I would step back and re-consider if I really should do it and if using a lambda a right thing for that case. So far (AFAIR), I never had to resort to any approach to overcome the restriction that variables used in a lambda must be effectively final.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, since clearly standard lib does not have it and your answer at least mentions a very common lib that has a class for that. As for your .02, I addressed that in my question.

Comment: I agree that Runnable could present more scenarios where this is needed, but still I think there are other options. One option that immediately that comes to mind is AtomicBoolean

Comment: Wouldn't that create an unnecessary impression that there's some multithreading going on? I was also worried that it has overhead.

Comment: Yes, that might not be the most intuitive solution when there is no multi-threading. Isn't there multi-threading already? I got that impression as you were using a Runnable and I assumed there are multiple threads and each thread needed to know the value of `somethingHappened`

Comment: No, my case was just doing `someList.stream().forEach()`